# SQL Error when trying to create a table. I modeled it after the exapmle that my professor showed us and I can't seem to find the error

Tags: sql-server

Error I'm getting

> Table level constraint or index does not specify column list, table 'Tag'.

Below is my code

```
--Creating the Tag Table
CREATE TABLE Tag (
--Columns for the Follower List table
vc_TagID int identity,
TagText varchar(20) not null,
TagDescription varchar(100),
--Contraints on the Follower List Table
CONSTRAINT PK_vc_TagID PRIMARY KEY (Tag),
CONSTRAINT U1_TagText UNIQUE 
)
--End Creating the Tag table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CONSTRAINT PK_vc_TagID PRIMARY KEY (Tag)
```

"Tag" is not a column of the Tag table

```
CONSTRAINT U1_TagText UNIQUE
```

You forgot to specify the column(s) that should be unique

Comment: Thank you, I realize what I was doing wrong once I read your response! Greatly appreciate your help @Gerard